# JSoup Unable to find input element

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to use Jsoup to connect to developers.amazon.com.

Here is my code:

```
Map<String, String> get_All_InputFields(Document loginPage) 
{
    Map<String, String> inputFieldMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Elements inputElements = loginPage.getElementsByTag("input");

    for(Element e : inputElements)
    {
        if(!e.attr("name").isEmpty())
            inputFieldMap.put(e.attr("name"), e.attr("value"));
    }
    return inputFieldMap;
}

String url_logon_str = "https://developer.amazon.com/home.html";
Connection.Response login_response = Jsoup.connect(url_logon_str).method.(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

Document loginPage = login_response.parse();
Map<String , String> inputFieldMap = get_All_InputFields(loginPage);
```

I am not able to logon. When I checked the Form data that gets posted, There is this input field by name metadata1 that I need to send when doing post.

But, the metadata1 is not present in inputFieldMap variable?

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting the `metadata1` field is because it is being added to the DOM by some JavaScript code.

You can verify this by using a simple REST client such as [REST Console for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn) to GET from https://developer.amazon.com/home.html.

You'll notice that there is no `metadata1` field in the returned HTML because the REST console doesn't automatically run JavaScript like your browser does.

There's nothing you can really do about this, Jsoup just *isn't* a browser.

I would suggest that this kind of problem is just the tip of the iceberg if you're trying to scrape Amazon's developer pages. If you dig around there may already be a published API or library that will do the task for you.